# Show that the index of $A$ in $\pi_1(Y, f(x))$ is finite and divides $m$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying for a qualifying exam problem and I am having difficulties with this problem.  I feel that the solution involves lifting properties, but I am not quite sure how to start.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be closed connected oriented 2ñmanifolds, and let $f :
X \rightarrow Y$ be a map of degree $m \neq 0.$ Let $A$ denote the image of
$\pi_1f : \pi_1(X, x) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y, f(x)).$
By considering the cover of $Y$ corresponding to $A$, show that the index
of $A$ in $\pi_1(Y, f(x))$ is finite and divides $m$.

Thank you for any help.